Noob question. How does transcoding help with editing? Won't it lower the quality of the final release?
Lets say I have a GH5 and I shoot in AVC/H264. I transcode it to Prores 442 for easier editing load. And I export to H264 mp4 again for web use, and prores 422 mov for master. wouldn't the footage degrade after all this?

If your original video codec is H264/AVC the compression was already there when you received the footage: So the transcode will only serve as a better encoding/compatibility/optimizing with the software your working with. The example you gave of course will degrade your footage because the treatment is making 2 "encoding downgrades" trips when you could just make 1 through working directly with the H264 files; You'll need to conform that sequence with the original H264/AVC files for getting better results on the final master, even though if you don't care about preserving the best quality for archival processes this may be innecesary or not important for you.
The main use of a transcode is optimizing the workflow between editor -- color grading suite + software codec compatibility and read speeds. Generally speaking the transcoder downgrades the 4K - 8K .arx file from an ARRI/RED/DJI cam into something like .mxf in HD for the editor to work on his laptop, this .mxf contains metadata for the color suite conform editor to reconnect with the original media files that are in 4K-8K and export VFX shots into something like .EXR - PRORES4444 with full resolution [Always mantaining the best quality files (CODEC - SIZE - COLORSPACE)] this back and forth mantains a Quality Control check verifying that the best quality files are always updated and without any problem between the trips. Then the final master is always exported from that timeline that the color grading technician has, and will be archived "for the future" to have the best quality preserving copy, or at least hoping to preserve it through time.
